# How to passby the "Win"/"Meta" Key on a fullscreen PyQt5 app?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

I develloped an application that is fullscreen and frameless so that the whole monitor only displays my application. I would like to prevent the user to make the taskbar appear whenever he hits the Win/Meta key on the keyboard (the key with the Windows logo on it generally).

In my UI class I already catch the press of that key:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Meta:
        pass
```

Instead of the `pass` instruction I already tried a bunch of things like:

- trying to ignore the event with `e.ignore()`,
- trying to accept the event with `e.accept()`,
- moving the mouse to a widget on the app and simulating a mouse click,
- bringing the app back on top via `self.show()` or `self.showMaximized()`,
- ...

But none of them managed to make the taskbar disappear. I really DO understand that Windows catches the press of the key before me and that the taskbar **WILL** appear, but I am wondering if there is some way to bring back the app on top straight after the taskbar appeared, so that the user has no time to quit the application without authorization.

The solution I search cannot be on the Windows side by disabling the Meta Key, because when the app is not launched yet, or not fullscreened I want to use the Win-Key.

Here my app so far :

```
class UserInterface(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UserInterface, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("HIM")

        # The app = the whole screen
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint, True)
        self.showFullScreen()

        # For unlocking him
        self.password_textbox.setEchoMode(2)
        self.password_textbox.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.unlock())
        self.password_textbox.hide()

        # A shortcut make the password box appear
        shortcut = QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("P,Y"), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(lambda: self.show_buttons())

        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Meta:
            pass

    def show_buttons(self):
        if self.password_textbox.isHidden():
            self.password_textbox.show()
            self.password_textbox.setFocus()
        else:
            self.password_textbox.hide()

    def unlock(self):
        pwd = self.password_textbox.text()
        if pwd == "my_password":
            self.showMinimized()
            self.password_textbox.setText('')
            self.password_textbox.hide()
```

If I press "P+Y", a textbox appears, and if I enter the right password, the frame is minimized (e.g. for maintenance).

Comment: Maybe, with the keyboard module, using [`block_key()`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.block_key).

Comment: this could be a nice option, however, Win catches the use of the key before my app !

Comment: Then I'm afraid that it's not possible. It's probably a system hook, not unlike the classic ctrl+alt+del: the OS takes precedence, and you can't do anything about it.